# How to style some words in a sentence using python pillow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I want to create images from text with some word highlighted by using styling like bold, underline, etc.

I'm currently using Pillow (PIL Fork) for this task but can't find an option which will allow this.

Following is a code snippet which allows me to generate images from text with some text-wrap.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw,ImageFont
import textwrap

 
bg_x = 800
bg_y = 600
bg_color = (73, 109, 137)

img = Image.new('RGB', (bg_x, bg_y), color = bg_color)

font_size = 35

font = ImageFont.truetype('/content/Roboto-Bold.ttf', size=font_size)

d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

#main text

text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."

margin_x = 100
margin_y = 100


d.text((margin_x,margin_y), textwrap.fill(text, width =30), fill=(255,0,0), font = font)
 
img.save('pil_text.png')
```

[image]

I want a very similar result but also want option of some words getting highlighted(bold or change color or italics, etc).

Anykind of hack or some other libraries in python which allow something like this is welcome.